# Create Array of Twitter Handles from String

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsstring

I'm looking for a way to analyze a string and create an array of all @Handles (like Twitter). With one small twist, @Handles can contain periods "."

So: @Username, @User_Name, or @User.Name.

My approach is with RegEx but I seem to be running into an error that I'm not sure how I'm producing.

My string is "@Albert and @David_Man and @Bob.Joe" but the array of usernames being returned is "@Albert, @David, @Bob", the RegEx is ignoring the underscores and periods.

Here is my code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]{0,30})" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:myString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, myString.length)];
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj returned nothing that time /:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you should try this...

```
NSRegularExpression *regexForUserNameTag = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: @"@[A-Za-z0-9._]{0,30}" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matchesUserName = [regexForUserNameTag matchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, yourString.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matchesUserName) {
    NSRange wordRange = [match rangeAtIndex:0];
    NSString* word = [yourString substringWithRange:wordRange];
    [usernames addObject: word];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Same issue, not getting "_" and "."

Comment: Copy pasted your code, Still not working... It is grabbing Usernames but not Usernames when they have periods and underscores like @User.name_one is only returning "@User".

Comment: I would think it is the regular expression... I don't know much about RegEx but I think your search string "@(\\w+)" would only return WORDS prefixed with an "@". "user.name_one" would be considered 3 words with non-words in-between.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63355/discussion-between-pankaj-wadhwa-and-albert-renshaw).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"@([a-zA-Z0-9_\\.]{0,30})" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:myString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, myString.length)];
NSMutableArray *usernames = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
  [usernames addObject:[myString substringWithRange:match.range]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry did you change anything? I'm still getting the same results

Comment: I didn't change anything in your three lines. I was under the impression that you had a working RE, you just wanted to get the array.

Comment: Ah okay! My apologies hahaa

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *badChars = @[".", ",", ";", ...]; //chars you don't want to be in username
NSString *string = "@Albert and @David_Man and @Bob.Joe";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for(int i=array.count-1;i>0;i--){
    NSString *str=array[i];
    if(![str[0] isEqual:@"@"]){[array removeObjectAtIndex:i]}
    for(NSString *badChar in badChars){
         str = [str stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:badChar withString:""];
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only work for the specific string I hard coded in... the code needs to be able to parse user input strings and strip out usernames.

Comment: Super dangerous to iterate in a positive direction while removing elements from the same array. Instead, you should iterate negatively, or copy to a different array.